# Cannot change files permissions on server. Could this be because my site does not have a domain name?

Tags: permissions, ftp, webserver, tinymce, whm

I am developing a site for a client who has not decided on their domain name yet. I set up an account on a web server via WHM but have not pointed any domain names to it.

All was going well until I used a plugin (TinyMCE) to try and browse files on the server - it wouldnt work so I had a look at its script files and realised their permissions are set to not executable (644). I tired to change it to executable (755) but I get an error in my FTP clients console:

```
550 Could not change perms on file.js: Operation not permitted
```

Could this be because I am accessing the server not through a specific FTP account and so the server has locked down the files?

EG: I am using the servers IP address to access files with my FTP rather then something like:

`ftp.mysite.com`

Any advice on this would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is an issues with the FTP account permission. You will have to login your server with the main cPanel account user name and password OR you can chnage your file permission through cPanel >> File manager